# Blackberry sqlite DatabaseIOException error file system 12

Tags: sqlite, blackberry, java-me

This is the error I get while trying to access a sqlite database from the 9800 simulator.

Before that I was developing under windows XP and save my code through SVN. Everything was ok and worked perfectly.

Now I use windows 7 64 bits and after checkouted my project I immediately got this error during the first execution : DatabaseIOException error file system 12.

Moreover, in the file system, the .sqlite is well created.

Is there any issue related to some specific rights or something else that occurs under windows 7 ?

Thanks !

Comment: I'm running W7 64 bit, and I can access the DB fine.  Is it possible you missed a project setting on the simulator telling it where to look for the file (e.g. hdd location of the simulated SD card)?

Comment: Well, I checked again all my configurations and it seems to be correct : in the simulator, I mounted a SDCard location in a folder of my choice.

Comment: Ok, as I cannot spend my time trying to solve problems that shoud not be, I killed my windows 7 and reinstall an old and stable windows xp on this new pc. Now I have the same correct behaviour as before. I suggest people which have the same problem to do the same : it seems like rim does not want to get a large community of developers as they do not provide a simple and efficient development environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BlackBerry tools do run on 64-bit Windows 7, but you must install the **32-bit version of Java** for them to run properly, not the 64-bit version of Java. See [my Windows 7 tips](http://www.blackberryprogramming.com/tips/windows-7-jde-eclipse/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your tips. It enforces my position concerning the blackberry development environnement and its lack of simplicity and efficiency. All the steps you are describing (and I guess it was a hell to find them) are just impossible to accept.